# Software for transliteration from Roman script to Devanagari script

Tags: language

I am looking for an offline software that can do the transliteration from Roman script to Devanagari Script. Is there anything available like this?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: And which transliteration scheme? Hopefully ISO 15919 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration

Answer (score 1):

There is Lingua-Deva which is a [perl](https://www.perl.org/get.html) language transliteration library available from [GitHub](https://github.com/glts/Lingua-Deva).

### Usage example:

```
use Lingua::Deva;
my $d = Lingua::Deva->new();
say $d->to_latin('आसीद्राजा');
say $d->to_deva('Nalo nāma');
```

Comment: I did also find a python library referenced but the links were broken.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it suitable for transliteration of all the filenames present in the folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml) module [sanscript.java](https://github.com/sanskrit/sanscript.js).

Quote from the ReadMe

By default, Sanscript supports the following Brahmic schemes:

- bengali
- devanagari
- gujarati
- gurmukhi
- kannada
- malayalam
- oriya
- tamil
- telugu

and the following Roman schemes:

- hk (Harvard-Kyoto)
- iast (International Alphabet of Sanskrit Transliteration)
- itrans (ITRANS)
- itrans_dravidian (ITRANS with support for Dravidian short "e" and "o")
- kolkata (National Library at Kolkata)
- slp1 (Sanskrit Library Phonetic Basic)
- velthuis (Velthuis)
- wx (WX)

When Sanscript sees the token ##, it toggles the transliteration state:

- Sanscript.t('ga##Na##pa##te', 'hk', 'devanagari'); // गNaपte
- Sanscript.t('ध##र्म##क्षेत्रे', 'devanagari', 'hk'); // dhaर्मkSetre

When Sanscript sees the token \, it disables transliteration on the character that immediately follows. \ is used for ITRANS compatibility; we recommend always using ## instead.

- Sanscript.t('a \a', 'itrans', 'devanagari'); // अ a
- Sanscript.t('\##aham', 'itrans', 'devanagari'); // ##अहम्

Comment: I want to use it for the transliteration of file names present in the folder. So, this scheme wont work there since the filenames doesnt contains `##`.

Comment: @Rohan Please note that the ## or \ is to force **not** transliterating specific parts of the string.  So this will work just fine.  You will just need to read up a little on how to write some java code to get it to take in a path and then get the file names, transliterate them and write them out.

Comment: sanscript.java seems to be javascript library not java & javascript doesnt have the capability to access system files.